# Encrypt Ruby code inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to ship out a gem to on premises for clients. I don't want them to know my code so I want to encrypt or obfuscate code inside the .gem file and ship it to them to integrate inside their ruby projects.

Any ref?

Answer (score 1):

There are no real obfuscation solutions for Ruby, as it is interpreted. The best you can get to make your application more *difficult* to reverse engineer is [AllInOneRuby](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/allinoneruby/index.html), but it will not provide real obfuscation. You can unpack this and get what you want relatively easily.

If obfuscation is super critical, I would encrypt all the scripts then make an application that wraps the Ruby C runtime, decrypts your script into a memory buffer, then invoke it. Then, pack all of that with something like  [Themida](http://www.oreans.com/themida.php) to stop people from attempting to attach debuggers (or, even if they do, understand the assembly, it'll all be `db [byte]` for the most part containing their VM's bytecode and not actual control flow instructions e.g. `jmp` `mov` etc). At this point you should have deterred the efforts of most inexperienced reverse engineers, but at the end of the day it is still security through obscurity.